# Creating/Accessing a JSON object using jQuery $.ajax with Last.FM API

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, last.fm

I've recently changed my site design and now need to use dynamic AJAX requests for my data. Basically, I'm trying to retrieve user data using the Last.FM API in JSON format.

I'm newish to this, particularly JSON, and it's giving me a bit of a headache! I know I must be missing something simple.

Here is some very basic code to test the functionality but it's not retrieving anything!

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./jquery/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getTopArtists&user=test&api_key=690e1ed3bc00bc91804cd8f7fe5ed6d4&limit=5&format=json&callback=?", function(data) {
        $.each(data.topartists.artist, function(i,item){
            html += "<p>" + item.name + " - " + item.playcount + "</p>";    
        });
        $('#test').append(html);
    });
});
</script>

<div id="test"></div>

</body></html>
```

Any suggestions?

I would like to be able to use the JSON object throughout the page so, for example, at any time I can just call topartists.artist[i].playcount; to display the playcount, etc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The html variable must be declared outside the scope of the `each`:

```
  //var topArt;
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getTopArtists&user=test&api_key=690e1ed3bc00bc91804cd8f7fe5ed6d4&limit=5&format=json&callback=?", function(data) {
        var html = '';
        $.each(data.topartists.artist, function(i, item) {
            html += "<p>" + item.name + " - " + item.playcount + "</p>";
        });
        $('#test').append(html);
         // topArt = data.topartists;
    });
});
```

As for your second question, you'll need a global variable. You can put it before `$(document).ready()` (as shown in the comment) and it will be accessible everywhere.

Comment: Thanks Val - I knew it would be something simple but that was just embarrassing :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following URL what you are using 
"http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getTopArtists&user=test&api_key=690e1ed3bc00bc91804cd8f7fe5ed6d4&limit=5&format=json&callback=?"

It gives not-well-formed json but if I use following URL
"http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getTopArtists&user=test&api_key=690e1ed3bc00bc91804cd8f7fe5ed6d4&limit=5&format=json"

I got the correct JSON.

Also you'll have to declare html as the response given above.