# Jquery (JSON) and last.fm API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, last.fm

I'm new in using JSON with Jquery and i ret some documentation and still cant get it to work.
I need pase data using JSON from last.fm API and get artist information (summary).

Link to API with artist Cher: 
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Cher&api_key=2b35547bd5675d8ecb2b911ee9901f59&format=json

Can anybody experienced write me simple example how to use Jquery to get an artist information from last.fm ?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103356/creating-accessing-a-json-object-using-jquery-ajax-with-last-fm-api?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with something like

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Cher&api_key=2b35547bd5675d8ecb2b911ee9901f59&format=json',
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data.artist.name);
  }
})
```

As you can see `data` is in json format, so you could access its properties using the dot notation.

Comment: Thank you for this, im really newbie in terms of JS and im finding things out :)
Can you please show me example how to get and artist image in large size :) thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Before asking, you should make a little Google search!

```
$.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Cher&api_key=2b35547bd5675d8ecb2b911ee9901f59&format=json', function(data) {
    var items = [];

    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
    });

    $('<ul/>', {
      'class': 'my-new-list',
      html: items.join('')
    }).appendTo('body');
});
```

Directly from [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) -- read documentation.

Comment: Thank you for this, im really newbie in terms of JS and im finding things out :)
Can you please show me example how to get and artist image in large size :) thank you very much.